# Auto login to itslearning using C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp, autologin

I want to auto login to a website (itslearning.com) and then display it in my Windows Forms Application with CefSharp.
It would be easy to do this with itslearning eLogin (https://developer.itslearning.com/Single_Sign-On_and_Authentication.html#284208891), but unfortunately my school doesn't support it.
Is there any other way to automatically login to my schools itslearning page?
May be save the login cookies? Or doing the same thing as the itslearning native app for mobile phones. The app uses OAuth2 for authentication. When you click on a link in the app (e.g. for the Dashobard) it opens the browser and you are automatically logged in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First start by setting the CachePath so cookies are persisted to disk see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown for an example. Do you have some specific questions? It's a little too broad currently, you'll need to do your own research to see if OAUTH login can be used with the website.

Comment: If you need to create a cookie then there's some guidance at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cookie-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
You can just use the itslearning Rest API:
[www.itslearning.com/restapi/help](http://www.itslearning.com/restapi/help)